# how to export vscode code format settings and import in rider

Tags: visual-studio-code, rider

in the team, my friends use vscode and I'm using rider and how to import vscode code format setting to the rider and I could not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s a feature in Rider that lets you import your shortcuts, recent projects and some plugins from Visual Studio Code. If you have an existing installation, you can reset Rider back to default settings to use this feature by clicking the “Configure” link on the welcome screen and selecting *“Restore Default Settings…”*  or go to *File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings*. You can read more at https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2021/06/10/import-settings-from-visual-studio-and-vs-code-to-rider/